# Serilog - path to log file

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

i am trying to start working with serilog. The normal RollingFile doesn't fit my needs (i need the counting like logs\20160701-00002.txt), so i want to use the RollingFileAlternate as a sink.

When using RollingFile i added

```
  loggerInstance = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
```

and was able to get the path from the App.config file with using:

```
  <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
  <add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="..\Log\MyLOG.LOG" />
```

Now i switched to RollingFileAlternate :

```
        <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
        <add key="serilog:using:RollingFileAlternate" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFileAlternate.logsDirectory" value="..\Log\test.log" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFileALternate.logsFolder" value="..\Log" />
```

I tried using logsDirectory and logsFolder since both are described in the examples of https://github.com/BedeGaming/sinks-rollingfile
but my program won't create a file.

if I add to the Loggerconfiguration:

```
        loggerInstance = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .WriteTo.RollingFileAlternate("..\\log")
```

the foldername will be used and the logfiles are put in this folder.

Can some one help me and tell me what i am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be a problem with the documentation; the argument is called `logDirectory`, not `logsDirectory`. So, you need:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFileAlternate.logDirectory" value="..\Log" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed to use "logDirectory". Now it is working.